# Custom JavaScript String Placeholders | Format Specifiers

Tags: javascript, string, customization, string-formatting, placeholder

### Ok peep's that last edit was poor here's the new one;

---

**Question:**
How do I intercept a string, or any object for that matter, as it is being parsed by the browser, in order to format it in a custom fashion before it is instantiated.

---

**Source:**
It can be done with **custom elements** using **lifecycle callbacks**:

```
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

proto.createdCallback = function() {...};
proto.attachedCallback = function() {...};

var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: proto});
```

---

**Logic:**

- Both the **custom element** & **string** are Objects...
- Both have a prototype

---

**Query:**
So how do I do it with the string `sz` in the example below?

---

```
format = {
    'abc123': function(p){
        spl = p.split(' ');
        spl[1]='<span style="color:red">'+      spl[1] +'</span>';
        spl[4]='<span style="color:orange">'+   spl[4] +'</span>';
        return spl.join(' ');
    },
    '123abc': function(p){'...'}
}

Object.defineProperties(String.prototype,{
    format: {value:
        function(){
            var spl, cnt, ia, itm
            spl = this.split(' ');
            cnt = -1;
            for(ia in spl){
                itm = spl[ia];
                if(itm[0] == '%'){
                    cnt++;
                    spl[ia]='<span style="'+ arguments[cnt] +'">'+ itm.slice(1) +'</span>';
                }
            }
            return spl.join(' ');
        }},
    fmt: {get:
        function(){
            spl = this.split('¦');
            ref = spl[0];
            str = spl[1];
            return format[ref](str);
        }}
});

sx = "I'm %Formatted with the %standardised method!".format('color:blue','color:red');
sy = "abc123¦I'm Formatted with a custom method!".fmt;
sz = "123abc¦I have no method call, but want to be formatted as I'm parsed!";

d1.innerHTML =  sx +'<br>'+
                sy +'<br>'+
                sz +'<br>';
```

---

### Hope you find this more on-topic...

---

Comment: I understand your incentive to share your achievement with us, but don't expect a warm response. First, there are already tons of template engines for Javascript, so it's unclear in the first place why you decided to write your own. Second, announcements of this kind are off-topic on StackOverflow - we are here to help each other, not to promote ourselves (at least not directly - it's fine to post your github link on the profile page).

Comment: Dude Im made up yeah. sure. but the question im askin requires some background to understand what im tryna achieve... never heard of a **template engine** before, aint got a github link, just cuz im on *Stack* don't mean im a master programmer.. I thought i was on-toipc most of the way? And theres no promotion involved im just after an answer to my question...

Comment: Where does `abc123` come from?  Anywhere in the surrounding scopes (i. e. somewhere, there is a `var abc123 = {"some": "object"}`) or from somewhere in particular?

Comment: _“Is it possible to do something like this”_ – it might be possible, but it doesn’t seem to make much sense. Especially that you want part of the string itself reference to an external object containing data seems quite unorthodox. Now implementing something `sprintf` like we know it from other languages like C would perhaps make more sense … but what you actually want to _achieve_ with this is still pretty unclear.

Comment: Why don't you just invent your own language to replace JavaScript? You could take some hints from SNOBOL.